# Do I need to have recaptcha for oAuth authentication?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, recaptcha

I allow users to sign up to my web app using the standard email and password authentication flow, as well as oAuth 2 with Facebook, Google and LinkedIn. I am planning to implement reCaptcha for the authentication form, but do I need to force the user to check the reCaptcha checkbox if they want to authenticate with any of the oAuth provider?

Answer (score 0):

There is no limitation regarding the authentication performed on the authorization server side.

It can be done through certificates or the classical username and password couple. 
You are free to protect the authentication form with a captcha or a 2FA protection (OTPs, email, SMS...).